# Perl script in loop ends after one run

Tags: perl, shell

I am running a Perl script in a loop in a shell script:

```
  while [ $currentDate -le $toDate ]; do
    // code here...
    exec /users/my_user/script_name $currentDate
    // code here...
  done
```

I have confirmed the `while-loop` loops. However, after one run of the Perl script, the `while-loop` ends.

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using `exec`. `exec` replaces the shell process with the new program. You probably want to just remove the `exec` keyword.

> `exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]`
>
> Replace the shell with the given command.
>
> Execute `COMMAND`, replacing this shell with the specified program.
>       `ARGUMENTS` become the arguments to `COMMAND`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
exec /users/my_user/script_name $currentDate
```

To:

```
/users/my_user/script_name $currentDate
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is caused by

```
exec /users/my_user/script_name $currentDate
```

what the exec causes is for the perl script that you are calling replaces the current program with the new one and keeps the current PID.

If you remove the exec from the line it will allow the program to spawn properly and keep the shell running as you expect.

Comment: @daxim sorry in my hurry to answer the question I missed that but I have updated my answer.